# Best direction to face while studying according to vastu shastra?

Tags: guru, vastu-shastra, gurukul

Is there any specific direction a student should face while studying according to vastu shastra?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.vastushastraguru.com/study-room-vastu-shastra-tips/

Student, while reading must face either East or North direction.